# Add Jpa Metamodel generated files using Gradle idea plugin to Intellij Idea sources

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, annotation-processing

I'm using the idea plugin on a Gradle multiproject configuration to generate the Intellij configuration files. At the moment the build is working fine in Gradle, but it gives me errors on the IDE due to the missing JPA Metamodel source files.

My question is, how can I place the generated .java files in a different folder and set them as a source folder for the modules in Intellij?

Currently I'm trying to send the parameter -s to javac but I keep getting the error `invalid flag: -s...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you want the generated source files to be compiled, the solution may be as simple as adding the source files to the `main` source set:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "build/generated-files" // adapt as necessary
```

Additionally, `compileJava` will need to depend on the task that generates the sources.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as Intellij ignores the source folders under 'build'. That's why I was trying to generate the source files in a different place sending -s to javac

Comment: Then just replace `build/generated-files` with `generated-files` in the above. You'll probably also want `clean { delete "generated-files" }` in this case.

Comment: I'd love to, that's the solution I'm looking for, but the compileJava task is generating the source files for me on `build/classes/main` and I'm trying to change that folder using the `-s` flag adding to gradle `compileJava {options.compilerArgs << "-s generated/java" }` but it gives me the error `invalid flag: -s...`

Comment: The correct syntax is `options.compilerArgs += ["-s", "generated/java"]`.